# Why my web services response return me data with first letter in lowercase?

Tags: php, web-services, postman

I have a problem with my web service response and i'm not able to fix this problem.

So i want to get a result with letter data in Uppercase, cause after that I don't able to see my informations.

Here this my code on web service :

```
    /**
     * @Route("/contact/getContactFilter/{tdlinx}/{soc}", name="contact_getContactFilter")
     */

    public function getContactFilter($tdlinx, $soc){

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager("APP_REFERENTIEL");
        $contactFilter = $em -> getRepository(CONTACT::class)->findBy(["TDLINX" => $tdlinx,"SOCIETE" => $soc,"ACTIF" => 1]);

        $encoders = [new JsonEncoder()]; // If no need for XmlEncoder
        $normalizer = new ObjectNormalizer();

        $normalizers = [new \App\Utils\DateTimeNormalizer(), $normalizer];
        $serializer = new Serializer($normalizers, $encoders);

        $jsonObject = $serializer->serialize($arrayUpper, 'json', [
            'circular_reference_handler' => function ($object) {
                return $object->getId();
        }]);

        if(!$contactFilter) return new Response(null,204);
        else return new Response($jsonObject,200, ['Content-Type' => 'application/json']);
    }
```

And this is my response on Postman and the problem is visible here at third part :

````
{
        "id": 63,
        "TDLINX": 257242,
        "TYPE": "physique",
        "SOCIETE": "B",
        "NOM": "Post",
        "PRENOM": "Strike",
        "COMMENTAIRE": "Test",
        "ACTIF": true,
        "INFOS": [
            {
                "id": 52,
                "VALUE": "006516451",
                "CONTACTID": 63,
                "TYPEID": {
                    "id": 15,
                    "lIBELLE": "Phone fixe",
                    "pATTERN": "phone",
                    "sOCIETE": "B",
                    "iCON": "local_phone",
                    "lIST": [],
                    "iNFOS": [
                        {
                            "id": 51,
                            "VALUE": "034455258",
                            "CONTACTID": {
                                "id": 169,
                                "tDLINX": 257242,
                                "tYPE": "physique",
                                "sOCIETE": "B",
                                "nOM": "Norris",
                                "pRENOM": "Chuck",
                                "cOMMENTAIRE": "Test",
                                "aCTIF": false,
                                "iNFOS": [
                                    {
                                        "id": 50,
                                        "VALUE": "Directeur adjoint",
                                        "CONTACTID": 169,
                                        "TYPEID": {
                                            "id": 17,
                                            "lIBELLE": "Poste",
                                            "pATTERN": "liste",
                                            "sOCIETE": "B",
                                            "iCON": "business_center",
                                            "lIST": [
                                                {
                                                    "id": 12,
                                                    "VALUE": "Directeur",
                                                    "TYPEID": 17
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "id": 13,
                                                    "VALUE": "Directeur adjoint",
                                                    "TYPEID": 17
                                                },
                                                {
                                                    "id": 14,
                                                    "VALUE": "Chef de rayon",
                                                    "TYPEID": 17
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "iNFOS": [
                                                50,
                                                {
                                                    "id": 53,
                                                    "VALUE": "Directeur adjoint",
                                                    "CONTACTID": 63,
                                                    "TYPEID": 17
                                                }
                                            ],
                                            "__initializer__": null,
                                            "__cloner__": null,
                                            "__isInitialized__": true
                                        }
                                    },
                                    51
                                ],
                                "__initializer__": null,
                                "__cloner__": null,
                                "__isInitialized__": true
                            },
                            "TYPEID": 15
                        },
                        52
                    ],
                    "__initializer__": null,
                    "__cloner__": null,
                    "__isInitialized__": true
                }
            }
}```
````

How to fix this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your database probably you defined id as "id"(first letter in small letter)

Comment: My columns are write in UPPERCASE